# Where can I get a LaTeX command explanation?

Tags: tex-core

For example, I do not know the definition of the LaTeX command `\ensuremath`. Where can I get its accurate meaning? Is there one professional website to offer some information about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What about https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX? There might be a huge amount of sites, of course.

Comment: I frequently just search for the command - e.g. Google `latex ensuremath` - and pick a link that I think will give me an explanation at the level I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source for definitions and meanings of LaTeX sources is [`source2e`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf). Specifically for `\ensuremath`, it states

> In math mode, `\ensuremath{text}` is equivalent to `text`; in LR or paragraph
>   mode, it is equivalent to `$text$`. `\relax` is not needed in front of the `\ifmmode` as
>   `\protect` will be `\let` to `\relax`. This version (due to Donald Arseneau) avoids
>   duplicating its argument in the ‘then’ and ‘else’ part of the `\ifmath` which is
>   necessary in nested ‘`tabular`’ like environments. See amslatex/2104.
>
> ```
> 305 \DeclareRobustCommand{\ensuremath}{%
> 306   \ifmmode
> 307     \expandafter\@firstofone
> 308   \else
> 309     \expandafter\@ensuredmath
> 310   \fi}
> ```

Then there are also numerous [LaTeX Help pages](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-2.html) compiled in HTML format. [Here's the specific one related to `\ensuremath`](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ensuremath.html):

> **`\ensuremath` (LaTeX2e)**
>
> ```
> \ensuremath{Text set in math mode}
> ```
>
> The argument of the `\ensuremath` command is always set in math mode, regardless of the current mode. Note that math mode is not specifically invoked in the argument of the `\ensuremath` command.
>
> Thus `\ensuremath{$\alpha^2+\beta^2$}` is not correct. The correct form is `\ensuremath{\alpha^2+\beta^2}`.